# Filter lines if number of string occurrence found?

Tags: linux, grep, logging, awk

Need to filter and show log lines, if line contains *exactly 2 commas*, and does not contains a specific string. Which linux command need I use, `awk`, `grep`, what is the expression?

For second condition I use this:

```
awk '!/specificstring/' ./log/file/path
```

Two comma check I do not know how to put in. Usually line is like this two:

```
arbitrary,arbitrary,arbitrary,arbitrary
arbitrary,arbitrary,arbitrary
```

Need the second type of line.

Tried something like this:

```
grep -P '[^,]+[,][^,]+[,][^,]+[,]"specificstring"[^,]+' ./log/file/path
```

How to exclude "specificstring"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest:

```
grep '^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*$' file | grep -v 'specificstring'
```

Answer (score 0):

This can can be done in one pass with `awk`, by combining the two conditions:

```
awk '/^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*$/ && !/specificstring/' ./log/file/path
```

The same can be achieved in `perl` with an almost identical command:

```
perl -lane 'print if /^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*$/ && !/specificstring/' ./log/file/path
```

To answer the question in its more generic sense, i.e. **filter lines if an arbitrary number of string occurrencies is found**:

```
perl -lane '@m = /,/g; print if scalar @m == 2 and !/specificstring/' ./log/file/path
```